# Save Mathematical Formulas

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

Want to save mathematical formulas into a SQL Server table and after pass values from C# to do calculation on formula which was save in table please guide ur helped is needed

Comment: Have you tried looking for a solution to your problem? Give us more information on what you have thought about so we can help you form an idea.  Don't just expect people to give you everything.

Comment: An example of what you would like stored would help also

Comment: my formula is saving in database as string Like (Insurancess / ROUND(Pipeline Rate, 4)) now have to pass values for these from C# so calculation can be perform in stored procedure like from C# code Insureancess = 3 PipelineRate =4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stored procedure to calculate result and pas values to stored procedure or get values form table using data base and calculate result and store result in database or show to user .

Comment: my formula is saving in database as string Like (Insurancess / ROUND(Pipeline Rate, 4)) now have to pass values for these from C# so calculation can be perform in stored procedure like from C# code Insureancess = 3 PipelineRate =4